# Is function `list` equivalent to using `cons` with a final cdr of `nil`?

Tags: list

I'm trying to explain Elisp to 5th and 6th graders and I tell them that `(+ 1 2)` evaluates to `3` and not `(3)`. So if I do want something that evaluates to `(3)` would I just evaluate `((+ 1 2))`? No! This gives the error message `Lisp error: (invalid-function (+ 1 2))`, which I explain by saying any list must have a function in the first element position, and having `(+ 1 2)` in the first position is not a function. Good. But again, how to get a result `(3)`? If I try `(list (+ 1 2))` I do in fact get `(3)`. Why does `list` evaluate `(+ 1 2)` then create the list containing `3`? `quote` doesn't -- and, no, it shouldn't. `(function (+ 1 2))` gives `(+ 1 2)`. As I understand,`list` is just syntactic sugar for `(cons (+ 1 2) '())`. Is this true? Can anyone explain some of the details of what I'm experiencing here -- or point me to a good explanation?

Answer (score 4):

+1 for teaching Lisp to 5th graders. And have fun! Lisp, like Logo, is good for kids.

---

Your question is a bit rambling. (Emacs.SE is not a place for tutorials or discussions - it's really for specific Q & A.)

I recommend that you take a look at the manual [*An Introduction to Programming in Emacs Lisp*](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/), by using `C-h i` and choosing **Emacs Lisp Intro**.  Work your way through it.  (Then maybe do likewise with your 5th graders.)  You won't regret it.

---

This is false: "any list must have a function in the first element position".

If you *evaluate* a list that doesn't have a function as its car then an error is raised.  But lists that do not have a function as their car certainly exist.  `(3)` is one such example.

---

Anyway, the answer to your question is that function `list` conses up its arguments, with `nil` as the last cdr. So yes, `(list (+ 1 2))` is equivalent to `(cons (+ 1 2) ())`.  It's generally more convenient to write `(list a b c)` than to write `(cons a (cons b (cons c nil)))`.

It's not about being syntactic sugar. Both `list` and `cons` are full-fledged Lisp functions.  It's not important how they might be implemented (e.g. in C code).

Comment: My specific question would be, Why does `cons` and `list` evaluate `(+ 1 2), then put the result in a list? In my presentation, I am trying to get across the uniqueness of building a language out of lists. This is one confusing aspect, i.e., why are some things evaluated, value returned, and others not?

Comment: *Functions in Elisp always evaluate their arguments.*
(Macros and special forms don't necessarily do that, and yes, sometimes we call those "functions" too, which I did when I said that an error is raised when you evaluate a list that doesn't have a "function" as its car.) `cons` and `list` are not macros or special forms - they evaluate their arguments.
You will do yourself, and your students, a favor by reading the Intro to Elisp manual.